# How to exclude multiple directories in ncdu when scanning

Tags: disk-usage

I'd like to see my disk usage using ncdu on / but exclude anything in `/home/` and `/media/`. But my command `ncdu / --exclude /home/ --exclude /media/` still scans those dirs.

Answer (score 4):

When you omit the slashes from the paths, it should work:

```
ncdu / --exclude home --exclude media
```

the documentation says about --exclude:

```
   Exclude files that match PATTERN. The files will still be displayed
   by default, but are not counted towards the disk usage statistics.
```

The pattern is about the *name* and not about the *path*.

Comment: thx! So that means if I have subdirs with a certain name that reoccurs in other places they will all be left out since I can not give a path?

Comment: that's how I understand the manpage. I tried it by creating /tmp/home with files in it. Indeed this directory is excluded by ncdu as well.